# Facebook login for Windows app using Javascript and html5

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, windows-phone-8.1

I am developing a windows 8.1 app using javascript and html5. I want to integrate facebook login.When I searched I found the following documentations

1.https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-for-windows-phone
2.https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web/v2.3

which one should I use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you go through the ***first link*** since it mentions `how to integrate facebook SDK in windows phone`. The other link mentions about Facebook integration through javascript in `web`.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the first one, I used js function in wp8

```
    Windows.System.Launcher.launchUriAsync("fbconnect://authorize?cliend_id=My_appId&scope=basic_info&redirect_uri=msft-my_prod_id://authorize").then(function (success){
})
```

It works for me, If I'm already logged with facebook app, it return true, else it show me Facebook Login Page. But I don't obtain Facebook userId, i'm able only to intercept boolean value for success or not. Did you get a solution for login and obtain Facebook userId?

Comment: Yes am using the facebook api for winjs https://github.com/Thuzi/facebook-winjs-sdk it works fine for me

Answer (score 0):

I found the Winjs sdk for Facebook
https://github.com/Thuzi/facebook-winjs-sdk
 it works for me.
For windows phone you need to use
 Windows.Security.Authentication.Web.WebAuthenticationBroker.authenticateAndContinue instead of Windows.Security.Authentication.Web.WebAuthenticationBroker.authenticateAsync during the login